# How to add count labels to the right of the bars in a horizontal bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example, this code

```
data <- data.frame(month = factor(c("Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb")),
                   count = c(1489, 788, 823, 1002))

g <- (ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes(x=month, y=count))
        + ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity")
        + ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits=rev(data$month))
        + ggplot2::coord_flip())

g
```

...produces this

[image]

What is the simplest way to add the counts (1489, 788, etc.) to the right of the corresponding bar?

I am particularly interested in the horizontal case, but I would also love to know how to do the analogous thing for the vertical case (counts on top of each bar):

```
g <- (ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes(x=month, y=count))
        + ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity"))

g
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you can replace `geom_bar(stat="identity")` with `geom_col()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `geom_text`. You also shouldn't need to specify the `ggplot2` package every time you call a function from it (although I don't know what else you have loaded!). The only difference between horizontal and vertical that you should be aware of is the `hjust` vs `vjust` parameters, which adjust the position of the label horizontally or vertically. (I've put these in because the default positions seem to be overlapping with the edge of the bar.)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=month,y=count)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=(data$month)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=-0.7)

ggplot(data, aes(x=month,y=count)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits=(data$month)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=count), hjust=-0.3) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image: horiz]
[image: vert]

Comment: Don't use `label=data$count`. Just `geom_text(aes(label = count), .....)`  will do. Also no need for the identity stat.

Comment: Alternatively, one could something like `hjust = 0, nudge_y = 2`, altough it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Axeman: Thank you!  What resource (book, website, etc.) would you recommend for learning all these details *systematically*?  I find that the documentation does not help in this regard...  One needs to already know what one is looking for in order to find it, which is Catch-22.

Comment: You can get a long way by looking at the [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.org/links/data_visualization_cheat_sheet) to find the function you need, then carefully reading the documentation and examples. Of course StackOverflow is a good resource too. I've heard good things about the ggplot2 book, and the R for Data Science book, but I've never read them.

Comment: The [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2/info) is also useful.

Comment: @heds1, thank you.  I'm almost there, but when I plot a small barchart, like the one in my original post, one of the labels falls outside the visible range.  How do I enlarge the padding to the right of the bars?

Comment: @Axeman thank you for the comment. @kjo I can recommend R for Data Science (you can go through it online, it's great). To enlarge the padding on the right of the bars, you can add `expand_limits`, for example, `expand_limits(y=c(0,1700))` will expand the y-axis to 1700. Be careful doing this when you have flipped the axes with `coord_flip()`, though, because the y-axis will appear as if it's the x-axis :)

Comment: @kjo I would also recommend using RStudio (since it looks like you're just using the console).